# Regex using sed

Tags: sed

I have lines that look like below

```
/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_1_2168.sorted.bam
```

I would like to extract the last part which contains .sorted.bam. that is

```
C03YABXX_1_2168.sorted.bam
```

What I am doing and is not working is

```
sed 's/.*sorted.bam//'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed 's/.*\///' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_1_2168.sorted.bam' | sed 's/.*\///'
C03YABXX_1_2168.sorted.bam
```

`.*` would match any character zero or more times greedily(longest match). So `.*\/` will match upto the last `/` symbol. Replacing the matched substring with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Through awk,

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file
```

`-F/` means we are telling the awk to consider `/` as Field separator. `$NF` variable contains the value of last field. So printing `$NF` will give you the desired output.

Comment: Thank you, for answering it and for explaining it.

Comment: Or just `awk -F/ '$0=$NF'`

Comment: What about `sed 's:.*/::' YourFile` :-)

Comment: yep, we don't even need to escape the forward slash if we use  different sed delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought why can't we use "basename" command here?

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ basename 'echo /abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_2_2168.sorted.bam'
C03YABXX_2_2168.sorted.bam
```

**Processing file content example**

Consider the following contents in file ff.txt, Suppose you need to process the 2nd line.

```
cat ff.txt
/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_1_2168.sorted.bam
/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_2_2168.sorted.bam
/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_3_2168.sorted.bam
/abh/HS200/110616_SN220_0066_AC03YABXX/Archived/C03YABXX_4_2168.sorted.bam
```

**Output**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ basename `grep "2_2168" < ff.txt`
C03YABXX_2_2168.sorted.bam
```